# Зачем использовать в рест приложениях стороние `JSON` библиотеки такие как `GSON`, `Jackson`?

Tags: java, json, rest, gson, jackson

Делаю пробное рест приложение. В процессе у меня появился вопрос, зачем использовать в рест приложениях стороние `JSON` библиотеки такие как `GSON`, `Jackson`, если контроллер возвращает объект в `json` формате. На примере моего кода мой контроллер возвращает мне нужный мне `json`, **не пойму смысла использования сторонних библиотек для сериализации**.

rest контроллер:

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CLIENT')")
public List<AccountListResponse> accountList(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
    List<AccountListResponse> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    accountRepo.findAllByClient_User_Id(userPrincipal.getId())
            .forEach(account ->
                    accountList.add(new AccountListResponse(
                            account.getUniqCheckId(),
                            account.getSum(),
                            account.getUpdatedAt(),
                            account.getCurrencyName().getName(),
                            account.getTypeAccount().getType())
                    )
            );
    return accountList;
}
```

accounts.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Data
public class Account extends UserDateAudit {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private BigDecimal sum;
@NotNull
private String uniqCheckId;
private boolean isBlocked;
@NotNull
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Client client;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "currency_id")
private Currency currencyName;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
private TypeAccount typeAccount;

public Account(@NotNull Client client,
               Currency currencyName,
               TypeAccount typeAccount) {
    this.sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00);
    this.uniqCheckId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.client = client;
    this.currencyName = currencyName;
    this.typeAccount = typeAccount;
  }
}
```

payload:

```
@Data
public class AccountListResponse {
private String accountId;
private BigDecimal sum;
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
private CurrencyName currency;
private TypeAccountName type;

public AccountListResponse(String accountId,
                           BigDecimal sum,
                           LocalDateTime updatedAt,
                           CurrencyName currency,
                           TypeAccountName type) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.sum = sum;
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Мой json:

```
    {
    "accountId": "804cd3da-7865-45b2-bf48-1cb471cb4484",
    "sum": 480,
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-15T09:40:26.302",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "type": "DEBIT"
},
{
    "accountId": "6e388506-04f6-410a-b63f-e3e7e9d24693",
    "sum": 0,
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-15T14:12:15.491",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "type": "DEBIT"
},
{
    "accountId": "bec1cb7c-8543-452d-bf3c-329b0e268468",
    "sum": 0,
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-15T14:12:22.591",
    "currency": "USD",
    "type": "DEBIT"
}
```

Comment: так контроллеры используют сторонние библиотеки для конвертации в джсон формат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Андрей, Spring использует по умолчанию Jackson для сериализации в json формат (если не переопределить). Смысл переопределения в том, чтобы предоставить какие-либо преимущества. Например, когда для JSON станет слишком "жирным" форматом и захочется немного облегчить выходные данные. Не помню точно, как называется, но сталкивался с библиотекой, которая большие списки сжимает по следующему принципу: в первой строке массива идёт словарь с описанием полей, а далее - матрица с данными. Таким образом мы экономим на исключении повторяющихся заголовков.
В других случаях может потребоваться ускорение маршализатора (хотя jackson лидер практически по всем параметрам) или что-то, чего jackson не поддерживает.

Answer (score 2):

То, что GSON или Jackson не используется **явно**, не означает, что они не используются совсем, внимательно посмотрите зависимости вашего проекта, и скорее всего найдёте там Jackson, который используется для сериализации в json.

Answer (score 0):

Например вам не нужно отдавать все поля клиенту и часть полей вы скрываете или наоборот добавляете(с помощью сеттеров), можете так же переименовывать поле которое отдаете.

Comment: Но вот в моем примере я не отдаю все поля пользователю, я отдаю выборочные поля, полученный объект из репозитория, я сериализую в промежуточный `AccountListResponse`

Comment: Как это...все 5 полей, которые у вас внутри класса отдаются клиенту(accountId, sum, updatedAt, currency, type)

Comment: А если вы их незасетите, то поле все равно придет, просто пустое

Comment: `AccountListResponse`, это промежуточный `payload` данный объект я использую для сериализации данных полученных из бд, чтобы пользователю отдать только то, что ему нужно. Я обновил, добавил класс, объект которого я изначально нахожу в базе... Там как вы можете видеть гораздо больше полей.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не увидел основную Entity. Ну как я вижу, вы создаете DTO(data transfer object) для этого всего, а с помощью либ это можно сделать без нее. По сути все в этих либах можно заменить DTO